# Casting a UIBarButtonItem to a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, casting, uibarbuttonitem

If I want to cast UIToolbar items to a UIBarButtonItem, XCode makes me write it this way:

```
    for item in toolBar!.items as! [UIBarButtonItem]! {
        // Do something
    }
```

However, once it does this it then says

> "Forced cast from '[UIBarButtonItem]?' to '[UIBarButtonItem]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?"

So, how do I write the above cast to a UIBarButtonItem without XCode showing any errors/warnings?

Comment: Below is a great collection of interesting answers, and all are very useful, thank helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [declaration of `items`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitoolbar/1617997-items?changes=_2)

```
var items: [UIBarButtonItem]? { get set }
```

It's an optional array of `UIBarButtonItem`, there is no need to cast anything. That's what the warning says.

Just check safely if there are items, `UIButton` is not involved at all.

```
if let bar = toolBar, let items = bar.items {
   for item in items {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

However if the toolbar and its items are designed in Interface Builder and won't be changed at runtime you can force unwrap both.

```
   for item in toolBar!.items! {
      // Do something
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if let` for safe type casting.

```
    if let items = toolBar.items {

        for item in items {
            if let btn = item as? UIButton {
                print("'btn' is UIButton.")
            } else {
               print("It is not UIButton.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way around it without any if / guard letting or force unwrapping is to use `forEach` instead:

```
toolbar.items?.forEach { item in
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if there are items then do a foreach.

```
// check if toolBar have any items
guard let items = toolBar.items else { return }
// then do a loop with items
for item in items {
    // do something
}
```

also you can use ?? to provide default value

```
// provide an empty array if items where nil
for item in toolBar.items ?? [] {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your warning says is that you are not changing a class (typecasting) but only force-unwrapping. In your case `toolBar!.items` is a type of `[UIBarButtonItem]?` and you are converting it to `[UIBarButtonItem]` which can simply be done by saying `toolBar!.items!`.

But this has nothing to do with `UIButton` you mentioned in your title. And you may NOT typecast `UIBarButtonItem` to `UIButton`. There is a big difference between the two as `UIBarButtonItem` is actually instructions to create a button and not a button itself. If you really need to get that button you will need to add it as a custom view using `UIBarButtonItem(customView: )` and then extract it as `item.customView as? UIButton`.